# Limiting collapse of divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a header for a login screen for a website im creating. The problem is when the user adjusts the width of the browser the form to enter the login info moves along with the border of the browser and looks strange when the browser gets too small. I tried setting min-width to 600px to limit how small the header can get (this seems to be the answer most people gave) but it doesn't work. I need it so that instead of following the right side of the browser as it gets smaller it should get a horizontal scroll bar instead and keep the screen a static width

Here is the corresponding HTML and CSS code:

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    
}


#header {
    
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #B0B1B5;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    min-width: 600px;
}

#logo {
    
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-top: 1%;
}

#button {
    
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 173px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;

}

#login {
    
    display: table-cell;

    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: 5px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="loginstylesheet.css"/>
        <title>Kindred</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="header">
            <a href="http://localhost/Kindred/register.php"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.gif" alt="Kindred - Login" /></a>
            <div id ="login">
                <form name="loginForm" method="POST" action="logininfo.php">
                    <label>Username:</label><input type="TEXT" name ="userName" value=""/><br>
                    <label>Password:</label><input type="PASSWORD" name ="loginPassword" value=""/>
                    <br>
                    <div id="btnHolder">
                        <input type="SUBMIT" id="button" name="loginButton" value="       Log In       "/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried setting the style overflow-x:scroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `#header` div is staying at a min-width of 600px.  That isn't the problem.  The problem is that your `#login` form has `position: fixed`, which means that its position is independent of its containing element (the header).  I believe what you want is for the `#login` form to stay at the right edge of the header and stop when the header stops shrinking (at browser-width of 600px).  Change the CSS of `#login` to

```
#login {
    display: table-cell;
    float: right;
    /* and add some margins and what-not here */
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05hm1n6f/)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your body's CSS to this...

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Comment: That adds a scrollbar when i get past the min width but the login form doesnt stay in position and keeps collapsing along with the browser